# Getting around IE double border behavior when using border-collapse

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In IE 8 (Standards Mode) a table set to `border-collapse:collapse` with borders on the `td`'s appears to double up the border.

The border is doubled up between cells, and also around the table itself.

[image: doubled up cell borders on IE]

The behaviour I'm looking for is more like the way that Chrome renders a border-collapse table. ie. the actual pixel width of a border collapsed between two cells (each with a border of 1px) is 1px.

[image: collapsed border (as desired) rendered in Chrome]

In the example pen that put together you can see the difference in rendering if you run this in either Chrome or IE to see the differences as above.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tfzus

Is there any way to make IE render the table single border as per Chrome?

I have tried `border-spacing : 0` but it doesn't affect a collapsed table.

**EDIT :** I have tried a positional based approach where I limit having adjacent borders based on cell position (taking care to use ':first-child' instead of ':last-child' for broader compatibility).  An example of this CSS is as follows...

```
table.formatted-table {
  border-collapse : seperate;
}

table td {
  border-right : 1px solid black;
  border-bottom : 1px solid black;
}

table tr:first-child td {
  border-top : 1px solid black;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  border-left : 1px solid black;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KACxv

I don't really see this as a an ideal solution, if you have a better one (ie. an obvious setting which I'm just ignorant of) please let me know!

I am using an HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but have tried switching doctype to HTML4 Strict to test this isolated issue. My page contains little else other than the code in the pen at the top of this question, so there are no other factors.  I've also tried this on multiple machines with my other dev mates in the office here running IE10 all with the same behaviour.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on IE 10 in IE 8 mode. If this really happens on IE 8, please check whether the HTML attribute `cellspacing=0` in the `table` tag helps. If not, I’m afraid you need to consider setting the borders in a more complicated way so that any adjacent borders are avoided.

Comment: I tried `cellspacing`, but I'm afraid it didn't help.  I'm getting this behaviour in IE8 and IE10 too.

Comment: @Teemu I'm not sure how that differs from anything mentioned before.  (cellpadding I believe I should rather do in CSS and is not relevant to the question is it? But I have also tried it out of superstition, it didn't help, thanks anyhow.)

Comment: This is strange, I don’t see double borders on IE 10 in any mode when viewing your codepen.io page. If I remove the `border-collapse:collapse` declaration, I see double borders between cells but single borders otherwise, as expected.

Comment: @Teemu, much appreciated anyhow! But I'll keep cracking on to find an answer.

Comment: Thanks @JukkaK.Korpela, I'll check on another VM and see what I get.

Comment: Not getting this in "normal" ie. What's doctype of the document?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` HTML5 doctype, using a few bits from HTML5 boilerplate, but mostly Twitter's Bootstrap.  For testing/isolating this issue I've been testing using a very simple clean page without the bootstrap/boilerplate css or scripts and have even tried switching doctype to HTML4 Strict to test.  Even though these are not viable for building what I need now.  I've tried this on multiple machines running IE10 all with the same behaviour.

Comment: Can’t reproduce that using IE 10 to emulate IE 8 either; a possible (if ugly) workaround could be to just give every table cell a bottom and right border only, and the table itself a top and left border to “close” it.

Comment: thanks @CBroe, thats what I'm doing in the second codepen in the post above, I may have to resort to that if no one can replicate this or knows of a setting that fixes this behaviour.